# Java - Char by char text file reading into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, file, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader

I'm attempting to return the array "seats" which is essentially supposed to return data from a text file - 15x30 grid of "#". I've tried a multitude of things, but I'm getting frustrated as I have VERY little experience with java. My code compiles but it doesn't print correctly when calling the method.

If anyone can help fix either the constructor or the method I would greatly appreciate it...and if there's any way you could refrain from using code that is terribly complicated I would appreciate it as well. And explain! Thank you!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class TicketManager
{
    private static int NUMROWS = 15;
    private static int NUMCOLS = 30;
    private char[][] seats = new char[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS];
    private double[] price = new double[NUMROWS];
    private int seatsSold;
    private int totalRevenue;

    public TicketManager()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("seatAvailability.txt"));
            String line = br.readLine();    

            while (line != null)
            {
               for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
               {
                   seats[i] = line.toCharArray();
               }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Error processing file: " + exception);
        }
    }

    public String returnSeats()
    {
        String result = "";
        for (int i =0; i <seats.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < seats.length; j++)
            {
                result += seats[i][j] + " ";
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the first and only method. I've been working with the constructor for so long that I've mistaken it for a method!

Comment: `for (int i =0; i <seats.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < seats.length; j++)` I would guess that `seats.length` needs to be changed to `NUMROWS` or `NUMCOLUMNS` as appropriate.

Comment: *"I'm sorry"*  An edit (and notification) is all I need.  No need for apologies.  :)

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that. The issue I'm having is that it simply won't print anything in my test driver (which I know there are no problems with). I'm almost positive it has something to do with the file reading.

Comment: BTW - general tips.  1) Test if the problem is 'file readin' by hard-coding the data in the source.  Does it still fail?  If so, it is not the file reading.  2) Try it hard-coded first, so then if it fails, we can run an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & see the behavior for ourselves. 3) Copy/paste the input, the expected output and actual output.  Use code formatting on them to ensure the line breaks are not lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight problem in your loop. Updated section of code below:

```
 public TicketManager(){
   try{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("seatAvailability.txt"));
       for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        String line = br.readLine();    
         seats[i] = line.toCharArray();
       }
   }catch(IOException exception){
       System.out.println("Error processing file: " + exception);
   }
 }
```

It will read 15 rows(lines) for input. Make sure you enter exact `30` characters in your each line. **Also don't use spacing in input line characters** e.g. your input for each line should be like `X0000xx00xx0xx0xx000xx0xxx0x00`

In your `returnSeats` method, use `seats[0].length` or `seats[i].length` in the inner loop and StringBuilder as:

```
public String returnSeats(){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i =0; i <seats.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < seats[i].length; j++){
            //append seat character in the result string
            result.append(seats[i][j]);
        }
        //append new line character in the string in between
        result.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `for (int j = 0; j < seats.length; j++)`, you need to have `for (int j = 0; j < seats[i].length; j++)`.

This has to do with how multi-dimensional arrays work. They are arrays of arrays. So when you write `seats.length`, you are asking how many rows there are. Calling `seats[i].length` asks how many members are in row `i`.